# Не получается подключиться через ssh к 192.168.7.2

Tags: windows, ssh

Пытаюсь поделиться Интернетом с PocketBeagle, но когда пытаюсь к нему подключиться в терминале через команду`ssh 192.168.7.2 -l root` выводило `ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22: Connection timed out`
Позже пробовал подключаться так: `ssh debian@192.168.7.2` результат тот же.
PocketBeagle подключен к компу через USB

Comment: SSH - сетевой протокол. Сомневаюсь, что USB его поддерживает.

Comment: А откуда такая уверенность, что у хоста именно этот ip? Кто ему его выдал?